# Importing a pfx from IIS to apache tomcat

Tags: tomcat, ssl, iis

I have a CA signed certificate which was requested through IIS and resulted with a pfx file.

When I use SSL to the IIS hosted site - everything is ok and the certificate seems to work great.

Now I needed to use the same wildcard certificate with Tomcat, since I didn't have a CSR or a private key file I used the pfx file exported from IIS. Unfortunately, using the web app showed the certificate is not signed by the CA.

So I went to GoDaddy and downloaded the certificates for tomcat (3 files):

- gdig2.crt
- gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
- 4e0...(long hash).crt

I then converted the .pfx file to jks using

```
 keytool -importkeystore  -srckeystore ./domain.com.pfx  -srcstoretype pkcs12   -srcstorepass PASS -destkeystore domain.com.jks -deststoretype JKS
```

Then tried to import the CA certificate with

```
keytool -import -alias root -keystore ./domain.com.jks -trustcacerts -file ./gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
```

I don't know if it's enough or in the right order but I tried several orders.
Now I message in from tomcat log says:

> DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=109, too big...

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for this.

Instead of exporting through IIS manager I exported the pfx through MMC.
Look at this link:
https://www.sslsupportdesk.com/move-certificate-iis-tomcat/